# Node Cannot find module 'D:\Education\nodemon\bin\nodemon.js'

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, node-modules, nodemon

- I am a beginner in NodeJS
- Environment is Windows 11 64 Bit.
- Node and Nodemon (Globally too) and NPM are installed and working.

  Now when I run the command

  > npm run server

It gives the following error

```
> devconnector@1.0.0 server
> nodemon server

'MongoDB' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'D:\Education\nodemon\bin\nodemon.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

Its looking in the wrong folder for the nodemon files. When I pasted the files there it worked fine but I want to change the folder
it searches for those files in.

Here is my server.js file

```
const express = require("express");

const app = express();

app.get("/", (req, res) => res.send("API Running"));

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}`));
```

And my package.json file

```
{
    "name": "devconnector",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "Social network for developers",
    "main": "server.js",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node server",
        "server": "nodemon server"
    },
    "author": "Sanket Pagadpalliwar",
    "license": "MIT",
    "dependencies": {
        "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
        "config": "^3.3.7",
        "dotenv": "^16.0.0",
        "express": "^4.17.3",
        "express-validator": "^6.14.0",
        "gravatar": "^1.8.2",
        "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
        "mongoose": "^6.2.9",
        "request": "^2.88.2"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "concurrently": "^7.0.0",
        "nodemon": "^2.0.15"
    }
}
```

Comment: I had the same issue when my project folder included a special character, i.e. "MySQL & Sequelize". In this case, when I started the project using `npm start', it threw me the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the file in the specified `D:\Education\nodemon\bin\nodemon.js` field in your `nodemon` module may be missing or corrupt. Have you checked the file? If there is no problem with the file, try reinstalling it the way you installed it, this will most likely solve the problem.

Have a nice day

Comment: There are no files there I don't know why is it using that path. I want to specify the path.

Comment: I think nodemon installed on C but you try work on D, search for this on stackoverflow or google. I think you can find result with that.

Comment: Yupp that's exactly it I want to enter the location manually

Answer (score 0):

The nodemon file or directory in that path does not exist , so you will need to install it again or install all your dependencies again using npm install or pnpm install

Comment: It does exist there as multiple projects which use that are still functioning properly